# Is there a way to prevent Thunderbird from downloading attachments?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, pop3, attachments

Is there a way to prevent Thunderbird from downloading attachments? I just want to download the message and leave attachments on the mail server. When I need to open the attachment I would then download it again from the server.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The best you can do is create filters that look for certain file types, like `x-zip-compressed`.

Comment: Sorry I can't get you. The problem is it takes time to load the entire message + attachments so I want to only load and read the message first then I would download the attachmetns later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Attachments are encoded as part of the message](http://www.livinginternet.com/e/ea_att_mime.htm), so no.

Comment: In IMAP, you can actually download only parts of a message. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5

Answer (score 4):

Check:

```
Menu -> View -> Message Body as -> Plain Text
```

furthermore, you have to change some values in about config, see [this articele in the german TB forum](http://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/viewtopic.php?p=340043#p340043)

you need to disable the default setting for "the holding of messages", otherwise TB always downloads the entire mail for offline reading. An attachment is indeed a direct component of the mail and not a separate file.
There should be **no filters** applied to the message body or attachment.

```
Menu -> View -> "Display Attachments inline"
```

must be checked.

In the advanced configuration then you have to Check if `mail.imap.mime_parts_on_demand` is set true.
also: `mail.server.default.mime_parts_on_demand`
Leave the entry `mail.imap.mime_parts_on_demand_threshold` on 30000 (= 30 KB)

because attachments less than 30 KB are rare (eg *.Vcf files, etc.) and do not interfere with the retrieval of mail.

also see: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Entire_message_fetched_when_opening_a_IMAP_message